# Using acts_as_paranoid with DelayedJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, ruby-paranoia

Can someone tell me precisely how to integrate `acts_as_paranoid` with `DelayedJob`?  I've tried creating a class `Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job` and adding `acts_as_paranoid` to it but even if I use an initializer and `require` the new class, acts_as_paranoid doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm not getting any errors so `paranoia` seems to be installed correctly and the job is cleanly deleted when it completes successfully - which is of course what I'm trying to prevent.

Happy to try any debugging suggestions if nobody reads this and immediately knows how I've screwed up.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I fell for the 'default scope' problem.  `acts_as_paranoid` changes the default scope so that a `find` only returns entries that have not been soft-deleted.  If you want to see ALL entries, including the soft-deleted one, you need to either add `with_deleted` as a scope for your query or, when adding `acts_as_paranoid` to your class, add as per the example:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid without_default_scope: true

  ...
end
```

With either of these changes, things are working.

Answer (score 0):

I know you answered your own question, sort of, but your answer doesn't help people landing here looking to actually integrate `DelayedJob` with `acts_as_paranoid` so I thought I'd explain this for others.

1. Create migration to add `deleted_at` to `delayed_jobs`:

   ```
   rails generate migration add_deleted_at_to_delayed_jobs deleted_at:datetime
   ```
2. Run migrations:

   ```
   rake db:migrate
   ```
3. Extend the `Delayed::Job` class to add `acts_as_paranoid`:

   **`config/initializers/delayed_job.rb`**

   ```
   class Delayed::Job

     acts_as_paranoid

   end
   ```

**That's it!**

Now when a job gets completed, you'll see that it doesn't get removed from the `delayed_jobs` table, it just gets a timestamp put in the `deleted_at` column so that the workers don't pick it up.

ProTip: The `deleted_at` column indicates when the job was completed as well.